# Cannot connect to xrdp on Fedora 25 from windows

Tags: fedora, vnc, xrdp

With a basic install, per:

```
dnf install -y xrdp
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
mv cert.pem /etc/xrdp/
mv key.pem /etc/xrdp/
systemctl start xrdp
systemctl status xrdp
systemctl enable xrdp 
firewall-cmd --add-port=3389/tcp --permanent 
firewall-cmd --reload
```

I get the following when trying to connect:

```
...
VNC error - problem connecting some problem
```

The content of `/var/log/xrdp.log` is:

```
[20170216-18:44:37] [INFO ] A connection received from: 192.168.76.11 port 63615
[20170216-18:44:37] [INFO ] A connection received from: 192.168.76.11 port 63615
[20170216-18:44:37] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 192.168.76.11:63615 - socket: 8
[20170216-18:44:37] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 7
[20170216-18:44:37] [CORE ] WARNING: Invalid x.509 certificate path defined, default path will be used: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20170216-18:44:37] [WARN ] Invalid X.509 certificate path defined, default path will be used: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20170216-18:44:37] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 8
[20170216-18:44:37] [INFO ] A connection received from: 192.168.76.11 port 63616
[20170216-18:44:37] [ERROR] Listening socket is in wrong state we terminate listener
[20170216-18:44:37] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 192.168.76.11:63616 - socket: 8
[20170216-18:44:37] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 7
[20170216-18:44:37] [CORE ] WARNING: Invalid x.509 certificate path defined, default path will be used: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20170216-18:44:37] [WARN ] Invalid X.509 certificate path defined, default path will be used: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20170216-18:44:37] [DEBUG] xrdp_0000105d_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
[20170216-18:44:37] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x0409 found and dosen't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20170216-18:44:37] [DEBUG] returnvalue from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20170216-18:44:41] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 12
[20170216-18:44:42] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 12
[20170216-18:44:43] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 12
[20170216-18:44:44] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 12
[20170216-18:44:45] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 12
[20170216-18:44:46] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 12
[20170216-18:44:47] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 12
[20170216-18:44:48] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 12
[20170216-18:44:49] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 12
[20170216-18:44:50] [DEBUG] VNC Error after security negotiation
[20170216-18:44:50] [DEBUG] VNC error before sending share flag
[20170216-18:44:50] [DEBUG] VNC error before receiving server init
[20170216-18:44:50] [DEBUG] VNC error before receiving pixel format
[20170216-18:44:50] [DEBUG] VNC error before receiving name length
[20170216-18:44:50] [DEBUG] VNC error before receiving name
[20170216-18:44:50] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 12
[20170216-18:44:50] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20170216-18:44:50] [DEBUG] VNC mod_exit
[20170216-18:44:50] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 127.0.0.1:3350 - socket: 11
[20170216-18:46:09] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 192.168.76.11:63616 - socket: 8
[20170216-18:46:09] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20170216-18:46:09] [ERROR] Listening socket is in wrong state we terminate listener
[20170216-18:46:09] [INFO ] A connection received from: 192.168.76.11 port 63630
[20170216-18:46:09] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 192.168.76.11:63630 - socket: 8
[20170216-18:46:09] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 7
[20170216-18:46:09] [CORE ] WARNING: Invalid x.509 certificate path defined, default path will be used: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20170216-18:46:09] [WARN ] Invalid X.509 certificate path defined, default path will be used: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20170216-18:46:11] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 8
[20170216-18:46:11] [ERROR] Listening socket is in wrong state we terminate listener
```

The content of `/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log` is:

```
[20170216-18:44:28] [WARN ] [init:46] libscp initialized
[20170216-18:44:28] [CORE ] starting sesman with pid 4144
[20170216-18:44:28] [INFO ] listening...
[20170216-18:44:37] [INFO ] A connection received from: 127.0.0.1 port 44184
[20170216-18:44:38] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 8 started successfully
[20170216-18:44:38] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username root, ip 192.168.76.11:63616 - socket: 8
[20170216-18:44:38] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
[20170216-18:44:38] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 9
[20170216-18:44:38] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 9
[20170216-18:44:38] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 9
[20170216-18:44:38] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 127.0.0.1:44184 - socket: 8
[20170216-18:44:38] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 7
[20170216-18:44:38] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 127.0.0.1:44184 - socket: 8
[20170216-18:44:38] [INFO ] Xvnc :10 -geometry 1904x1003 -depth 24 -rfbauth /root/.vnc/sesman_root_passwd -bs -nolisten tcp -localhost
 -dpi 96
[20170216-18:44:38] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sessvc - xpid=4196 - wmpid=4195
[20170216-18:44:38] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username root, display :10.0, session_pid 4194, ip 192.168.76.11:63616 - socket: 8
```

Comment: Did you ever make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a graphical environment on the server. Replace `dnf` with `yum` if dnf is not working.

```
# dnf install @kde-desktop              [KDE Desktop]
# dnf install @xfce-desktop             [XFCE Desktop]
# dnf install @mate-desktop             [Mate Desktop]
```